# Change image for UIButton created inside UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have created a `UIbutton` inside a `UITableView`. I have multiple rows. On touching the button of a particular row I want the image of that particular button to change. The button I am adding is a checkbox. So every time I touch the button, its image will change.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

/*  

Some code  

*/  

 //Checkbox
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-not-checked.png"];
        btnConfirm = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnConfirm.tag =[[arrID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]; 
        [btnConfirm setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnConfirm.frame = CGRectMake(checkboxXX, 10.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
        [btnConfirm addTarget:self action:@selector(AddToCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btnConfirm];  

}  



-(void)AddToCart:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnTemp=sender;
    int iTag = btnTemp.tag;  

    // I want to change image of sender

}
```

Comment: you want to change the similar image for all the buttons ?

Comment: Yes. Checkbox(button) is in every row.

Comment: But on touching a button image of only that button should change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)AddToCart:(id)sender

{
UIButton *btnTemp = (UIButton *)sender;
int iTag = btnTemp.tag;  

// I want to change image of sender
[btnTemp setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Try this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stack overflow says I can accept your answer in 3 minutes. I'll do so :)

Comment: Hi @7KV7 i want if i select another check box then previous check box should be unselected

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
-(void)AddToCart:(UIButton *) addButton
{
   [addButton setImage:yourImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The type of the sending object doesn't have to be `id`

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
-(void)AddToCart:(id)sender

{
UIButton *btnTemp = (UIButton *)[yourTableView viewWithTag:sender];
int iTag = btnTemp.tag;  

// I want to change image of sender
[btnTemp setImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: Will this 
`UIButton *btnTemp = (UIButton *)[yourTableView viewWithTag:sender];`
 work? Will you get the button when you say `[yourTableView viewWithTag:sender];`